# Accessing source observable from outside Rx.Observable.prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I am having trouble figuring out how to access the source observable, in this scheme (just trying to figure out how to this without modifying Rx.Observable.prototype):

```
      q.drain()
        .flatMap(function(val){
            return q.backpressure(val, function(cb){
                   setTimeout(cb,1000);
            });
        })
```

We call backpressure as a method on the Queue prototype:

```
Queue.prototype.backpressure = function(val, fn){

    const source = ? // I don't know how to access the source observable...

    return Rx.Observable.create(sub => {

        return source.subscribe(val => {

                fn.call(source, val, function(err, val){
                    if(err){
                        sub.error(err);
                    }
                    else{
                        sub.next(val);
                    }

                });
            },
            // be sure to handle errors and completions as appropriate and
            // send them along
            err => sub.error(err),
            () => sub.complete());

    });
};
```

but the problem is I don't know if I can access the source observable in this scheme - the correct value for source is certainly *not* the `this` value inside the prototype because that belongs to the queue instance. My only hope I think is somehow to pass the source observable directly into the backpressure method. Anyone know how I can this? I don't mind putting this function elsewhere, it doesn't have to be a method on queue, but I think the same problem will exist either way.

If it helps, the value for `this` inside the flatMap function (if you use a regular function instead of an arrow function) is a MergeMapSubcriber object, see:

[image]

However, after experimenting, I don't believe that the MergeMapSubcriber value is the one I want to use as my source; my source should be an Observable TMK, not a Subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about putting it on `Observable` prototype?

```
Observable.prototype.backpressure = function(queue, fn){
  const source = this;

  return this.flatMap(function(val){
    return Rx.Observable.create(sub => {

      return source.subscribe...
    });
  })
};
```

Then for queue:

```
q.drain()
  .backpressure(q, function(cb) {
    setTimeout(cb,1000);
  });
```

Comment: yeah that would be fine, but would be nice to figure out how to do it without putting it on the prototype, at the very least as an exercise, there must be a way!

Comment: I updated the OP, let me know if that offers any more useful info

Comment: @Alexander Mills, Do not think you can reach it from `flatMap`.

Comment: actually, I don't think you need to reach the source from flatMap, I think I may be overthinking it

Comment: in other words, when using flatMap - I think the RxJS library does the connecting of source to destination for you, you do not need to it manually, you are only providing the transformation.